# Get custom object by id from json java jsonpath

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

I'am trying to get User object from json by Jayway JsonPath.
My class is:

```
 public class User{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    /*getters setters constructor*/
  }
```

And json example:

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "login": "client1",
      "password": "qwerty",
      "email": "client@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanna to get smth like this:

```
public Optional<User> find(String id) throws NoSuchEntityException {
    Optional<User> user = Optional.empty();
    try{
        Path path = Path.of(fileDestination+fileName);
        ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(Files.readString(path));
        User readUser = ctx.read("$..user[*]",User.class,Filter.filter(where("id").is(id)));
        user = Optional.ofNullable(readUser);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;
}
```

Or to get good advice how to code it:D

Comment: Glad I could help. I noticed you never accepted or upvoted an answer, please follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers & https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

two things here

1. you must use the placeholder `?` instead of `*` when you're filtering, otherwise, the filter will be ignored.
2. `read()` will return a list, not a single object.

so, I think, you need something like this

```
String json = "{\r\n"
        + "  \"user\": [\r\n"
        + "    {\r\n"
        + "      \"id\": \"1\",\r\n"
        + "      \"login\": \"client1\",\r\n"
        + "      \"password\": \"qwerty\",\r\n"
        + "      \"email\": \"client@gmail.com\"\r\n"
        + "    }\r\n"
        + "  ]\r\n"
        + "}";

Predicate filterById = filter(where("id").is("1"));
List<User> users = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.user[?]",filterById );

System.out.println(users);
```

Reference: [Filter Predicates](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-predicates)

> ```
> where("category").is("fiction").and("price").lte(10D) );
>
> List<Map<String, Object>> books =     
> parse(json).read("$.store.book[?]", cheapFictionFilter);
> ```
>
> Notice the placeholder `?` for the filter in the path. When multiple filters are provided they are applied in order where the number of placeholders must match the number of provided filters. You can specify multiple predicate placeholders in one filter operation `[?, ?]`, both predicates must match.

Comment: `$.user[?]` isn't valid JSON Path syntax. Is this actually supported by Jayway? What does it do?

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath see "Filter Predicates".  Looks like it's a mechanism employed by this library that functions similarly to string interpolation, but for injecting filters defined elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, the placeholder `?` works similar to a bind param in an SQL query.